# Installing and Running WCF Service inside a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I am not a C# or .NET expert. However, I must use it...

I am running `InstallUtil.exe MyService.exe` to install a Windows Service that is essentially running a WCF service. I have defined the WFC Interface and implemented it as well. Below is the interface.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://WCFService", Name = "WCFService")]
public interface IWCFService
{
    [OperationContract]
    User Login(string userName, string password);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Project> GetProjects(Guid userGuid);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Stylesheet> GetStylesheets(Guid projectGuid);

}
```

I have also defined a Windows Services as follows:

```
public partial class Service: ServiceBase
{
    public FlatWsdlServiceHost m_fwsh = null; // extends ServiceHost

    public DesignerService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnStart Successfull", EventLogEntryType.Information);

        if (m_fwsh != null)
        {
            m_fwsh.Close();
        }

        // Create a ServiceHost for the EventWebService type and 
        // provide the base address.
        Uri localUri= new Uri("http://localhost:7777/");
        m_fwsh = new FlatWsdlServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), localUri);

        // Open the ServiceHostBase to create listeners and start 
        // listening for messages.
        m_fwsh.Open();
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //base.OnStop();

        if (m_fwsh != null)
        {
            m_fwsh.Close();
            m_fwsh = null;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
    }
}
```

When I run the `InstallUtil.exe MyService.exe` the logs say:

```
Installing assembly 'MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = MyService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = MyService.exe
No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the MyService.exe assembly.
Committing assembly 'MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = MyService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = MyService.exe
No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the MyService.exe assembly.
Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.
```

Also, I do have a ProjectInstaller.cs which initializes the serviceInstaller1 and serviceProcessInstaller1. Prior to adding the WCF Service the Windows Service was installing fine and writing the 'OnStart Successfull' message to the Windows logs.

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated.

Comment: When you added the installer, did you right-click on the service design surface and select "Add Installer"?

Comment: For more details on adding an installer see the "Create a Windows Service project" section here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317421

Comment: @PeterRitchie Yes, I did however, I added the Installer before adding the WCF Service. Could that cause the problem?

Comment: No, it should not. Actually, installation of Windows service have nothing to do with WCF - no dependencies between them.

Comment: @drunkenRabbit +1 to evgenyl's comment.  that shouldn't cause any base installation issues

Comment: @evgenyl that can be ruled out at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need class like this:

```
// Provide the ProjectInstaller class which allows 
// the service to be installed by the Installutil.exe tool
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ProjectInstaller : Installer
{
    private ServiceProcessInstaller process;
    private ServiceInstaller service;

    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        process.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
        service = new ServiceInstaller();
        service.ServiceName = "WCFWindowsServiceSample";
        Installers.Add(process);
        Installers.Add(service);
    }
}
```

Full tutorial is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Comment: Is you class public and have attribute RunInstaller and it is in MyService.exe? The error makes it clear that such class is missing: "No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the MyService.exe assembly."

Comment: No idea what the problem was. But I deleted and recreated an Installer for the Service, and it worked...